# Tascam US-322 not working on Ubuntu 15.04

Tags: sound, 15.04

Is anyone able to help with my sound problems? I have ubuntu 15.04 installed and am using a Tascam US-322 external USB 2 soundcard, however this is not detected or an option in the list of devices available. Please bare in mind that I am very new to Linux and don't know much about short speak for commands software or stuff in terminal. Can anyone put simply (if possible) how I would get this device to work on Ubuntu (I really want to start moving away from Windows).

I find drivers for windows and mac but not linux:
http://tascam.com/product/us-322/downloads/

I've also checked out another post on the forum for the tascam us-322 on 14.04 but it didn't work.

Thanks

D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tascam does not provide drivers for many of its AI products.  I have tried many times to get the company to reconsider but they seem to feel as if Linux is not worth their time and money.  Many have also asked that the company release an open-sourced version of their driver but every request is met with silence.  I would suggest selling your unit and getting a Focusright Audio Interface which is FAR more Linux/BSD friendly.